# How to get rid of degree symbols on the axis text in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a map that I've created using ggplot. The text on the x and y axis are longitude, and latitude values. When I add my values from my dataframe to the map they have degree symbols next to them but I want to get rid of the degree symbols. I only want the degree symbol in my axis title. My map looks like this.

[image]

Below, is the code I used to import the map, and plot my data with. I've specified where these degree symbols are coming from

```
canada = map_data("worldHires", "Canada")

ggplot(data = canada) +
  geom_polygon(data = canada, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "grey") +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45), expand = FALSE) +
  labs(x=expression(paste("Longitude ",degree,"W",sep="")),
       y=expression(paste("Latitude ",degree,"N",sep=""))) +

  #Here is where the degree symbols are added
  geom_point(data = mapindividual_dets,
             mapping = aes(x = longitude, 
                           y = latitude),
             size = 10)
```

Here is a sample of the dataframe I have that is giving me the issues. I can't put it all on here because it is too large.

```
mapindividual_dets = structure(list(location = c("ARB-04", "BIRCHY HEAD", "Boca1", 
                                                 "BON-AR-S2", "BON-AR-S2", "BON-W-S5"), month = structure(c(12L, 
                                                                                                            10L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
                                                                                                                                               "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "factor")), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), animal_id = c("NSTR-007", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "NSTR-007", "NSTR-021", "NSTR-007", "NSTR-007", "NSTR-007"), 
                                    detection_count = c(3L, 256L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), num_unique_tags = c(1L, 
                                                                                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), total_res_time_in_seconds = c(0, 1182040, 
                                                                                                                                                          0, 2732221, 0, 0), latitude = c(24.94808, 44.5713, 26.32559, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          -49.27732, -49.27732, -49.27985), longitude = c(-80.45412, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -64.03512, -80.07108, 69.48038, 69.48038, 69.47853)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            location = c("ARB-04", "BIRCHY HEAD", "Boca1", "BON-AR-S2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "BON-AR-S2", "BON-W-S5"), month = structure(c(12L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       8L, 11L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "factor")), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the degree symbols on the axis text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supply your own labels. You can use a function. I recommend `I`, if you want to keep the sign (as e.g. degrees West are coded as negative) or `abs` if you don't want the sign.

```
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
ggplot(nc) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
    scale_x_continuous(label = abs) +
    scale_y_continuous(label = abs)
```

[image]